# Данные об организациях по адресу полученные разными способами - отличаются

Tags: yandex-places-api

Для получения данных об организациях я использую yandex maps API описанное тут:

```
https://yandex.ru/dev/geosearch/doc/ru/concepts/request
```

Данные приходят, но если тот же самый адрес забить просто в Яндекс карты и посмотреть организации, то они отличаются (адрес точно тот же).

Привожу пример конкретного запроса:

```
https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?text=Москва, Новозаводская улица, 22&type=biz&results=50&lang=ru_RU&apikey=...
```

Тут мне выдаются вот такие организации:

- Улица Новозаводская, 22 (Автомобильная парковка)
- Парковка (Автомобильная парковка)
- Международная Ассоциация Исламского Бизнеса (Бизнес-консалтинг, Инвестиционная компания)
- Новозаводская улица (Остановка общественного транспорта)

А вот как эти же самые организации выглядят в картах:

```
https://yandex.ru/maps/213/moscow/?text=Москва, Новозаводская улица, 22
```

Тут у нас:

- Бизнес-отель Протон
- Сбербанк
- Международная Ассоциация Исламского Бизнеса
- Бери заряд

Общая только Ассоциация Исламского Бизнеса. Остальные три организации разные. Почему так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Яндекс не разрешает выгружать в пользовательские базы объекты их справочника *(а вы, похоже, именно это и хотите делать)*. Потому и сервис API ППО не предназначен для решения такой задачи.

Этот сервис создан, чтобы искать конкретные организации или их категории, а не возвращать их список по какому-то адресу. Запрос "***Москва, Новозаводская улица, 22, Сбербанк***", например, вернёт корректный результат – отделения Сбера по указанному адресу и ближайшим к нему.

Comment: Идея заключается в том, чтобы по нажатию на маркер моей карты - я мог видеть все организации, находящиеся по адресу. Если этот API не предназначен для этого, то может есть другой способ получить организации по конкретному адресу?

Comment: Организации Яндекс оставляет себе – это их отдельный сервис – Бизнес. И работу с организациями не реализуют через API именно по этой причине – чтобы работали с этой инфой именно на карте Яндекса и в их продуктах, а не свои копии делали. Можете просто встроить на сайт виджет карт (код через кнопку "Поделиться") – там все дома кликабельные и есть кнопка "организации в доме", открывающая страницу Яндекс Карт со списком.